# Azure relay hybrid connection - multiple servers (one premise) one client

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-servicebusrelay

I want to build a service using Azure relay hybrid connection. The service will be downloaded by the customers and installed on their premise. The service itself is a server basically that will allow a client to connect to and get data from a database. I am following this scenario here : [Azure Relay Hybrid Connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-relay/relay-hybrid-connections-dotnet-get-started) and works fine when you have one client and one server. My scenario is something like this (one client and many servers):

[image]

How can I build a dynamic server in such way that one client can connect to a specific server and get the data from the database?

I was thinking about having some config file that is generated when the customer downloads the server and the server will read the settings from the file, but still how do I connect to a specific server? Azure service bus topics and subscriptions work in similar way. Can this be achieved using the relay hybrid connections?

Comment: Can you provide some more details on your workflow? What type of data is exchanged? When is data requested/received? Based on what I have heard so far, I think you have the client/listeners flipped. You would want your service hosted in Azure to be the listener(s), both for billing, but also because client data will be load balanced across listeners.

Comment: @JTaub: The flow goes something like this: There is a scheduled job that runs let's say once a day in Azure. The job will connect to specific customer premise service and get the data as JSON.

Comment: Any reason you'd wouldn't just push the data as it becomes available? That is probably a better design practice to follow with Hybrid Connections. For example, you would have your Azure service, which connects as a Hybrid Connection listener (which can also have multiple connections/listeners), then your clients (on-prem db agents) would connect and push data to the listeners. However, only one listener would receive the data.

Comment: @JTaub: The whole schedule is done in the cloud. Maybe the customer will decide that I want the data to be sync 2 or 3 times per day at different hours. For that I can use a scheduler to trigger the data collection when the customer wants. I am also thinking to implement own websockets solution for that ... but maybe I can achieve this with hybrid connection or service bus topics. I got a reply from Clemens Vasters from Microsoft that the scenario should be possible in hybrid but also using the topics service bus